# I need VBA to write " Output Example:" and then move the items in Column I to after the text "Output Example"

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I attached 2 photos. One of what the document looks like, the other of what I want. I have items with definitions in column H and output examples in column I but I need the definition and output example to be combined. So I need code that writes "Output Example:" after whatever text is in Column H and then moves the text from Column I and puts it after the text "Output Example:" The catch is, if column I is blank, I don't want the word "Output Example" to be written into Column H because then that would be confusing.

This is for 1,000 rows of data.

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7epv8.png)
[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfUOB.png)

```
    Sub MacroForOutput()
'
' MacroForOutput Macro
'

'
    Range("H8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "The prior authorization code specifying the type of authorization. Output Example: " & Chr(10) & ""
    Range("I8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "111"
    Range("H8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "The prior authorization code specifying the type of authorization. Output Example: 111" & Chr(10) & ""
    Range("H9").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post the [code you have already](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: I posted the code. sorry about that. I just don't understand how to get a macro to continue down the line when I write a macro.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code does the job for one row, below is a for loop for 2000 rows.

```
Sub MacroForOutput()
'
' MacroForOutput Macro
'

'
    For i = 2 To 2000
    Range("H" & i).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "The prior authorization code specifying the type of authorization. Output Example: " & Chr(10) & ""
    Range("I" & i).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "111"
    Range("H" & i).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "The prior authorization code specifying the type of authorization. Output Example: " & i & Chr(10) & ""
    Range("H" & i).Select
    Next i
End Sub
```